# Trouble to deploy Python application in Google Cloud

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, deployment, cron, peewee

I'm trying to deploy a Python application in Google Cloud, using an Ubuntu virtual machine. The script should be executed every 1 minute. I have already deployed it, and when I execute it manually, it works perfectly, however, when I run by using a cronjob, it returns empty, but there are records in the database. I have already changed permissions, but nothing changed. I'm also using the full path to the database but didn't work. I'm using Peewee ORM to deal with the database.

The Peewee Model

```
from peewee import (
    SqliteDatabase, Model, TextField, ForeignKeyField,
    DateTimeField, IntegerField, FloatField, CharField, BooleanField
)
import os
from datetime import datetime

absolute_database_path = os.path.abspath("./teste.db")
db = SqliteDatabase(absolute_database_path)

class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db


class User(BaseModel):
    name = TextField()
    email = TextField(unique=True)
    phone = TextField()
    age = IntegerField()
    created_at = TextField(default=datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))
    updated_at = TextField(default=datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))
```

The Script

```
from models import User


def get_all_users():
    try:
        users_query = User.select().dicts()
        users = []
        for user in users_query:
            users.append(user)
    
        print(users)

        return users
    except Exception as e:
        message = f"Occurred an exception while retrieving users. {e}"

        print(message)
        return message
        
print(get_all_users())
```

The Cron job

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/python3.9 /var/www/myscript/main.py >> /var/www/logs/logfile.log 2>&1
```

I have tried to change the permissions of the database, also have specified the full path of the database, tried to log the script, and tried to execute it manually. When the script is executed normally, it retrieves the users from the database, however, when the cron job executes the script, it only returns empty. How can I solve that?

Comment: You might try adding `if __name__ == '__main__': print(get_all_users())` ?